# I can not receive sms in twilio?? "twilio" "sms"

Tags: twilio, sms, twilio-programmable-chat

I cannot receive SMS in twilio in order to receive activation codes. I tried to send a code to twilio but the message did not arrive and I tried again via my mobile phone number to send to twilio number but it did not arrive??
I don't know if the problem is with Webhook to POST or MESSAGING SERVICE.
A note is shown to me
Routing
United States (US1) Region inbound message routing is: Active

I have a twilio GB number.     "twilio" "sms"

I cannot receive SMS in twilio in order to receive activation codes. I tried to send a code to twilio but the message did not arrive and I tried again via my mobile phone number to send to twilio number but it did not arrive??
I don't know if the problem is with Webhook to POST or MESSAGING SERVICE.
A note is shown to me
Routing
United States (US1) Region inbound message routing is: Active

I have a twilio GB number.

Comment: Please provide some code so we can understand what isn’t working!

Comment: Is this an activation/confirmation code for a product or service that requires a mobile number? This is to ensure the product or service is not abused and you are in fact a single user, as any other scenario generally violates the product or service's terms and conditions that you are now bound to. This can also leave Twilio theoretically liable for facilitating this. This can also devalue Twilio's asset (its recyclable phone numbers) if they are frequently misused and placed on third-party verification lists that restrict or limit use or access. This is unfair to legitimate developers like me